# Omnet: How to extract data from CMessage

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I need to obtain the data part from Cmessage by converting into a const char* or something. I did take a look at Cmessage.h. But, I have not been able to understand it much

Answer (score 3):

The way I'm adding some data to messages is by creating a new object and attaching it to the message. As the message is passed around the network, whenever it reaches a node, I'm extracting the object from it.
The code goes something like this:

```
cMessage *msg = new cMessage("message"); // create a new message

NewObject *newObAdded = new NewObject();  // create your new object

msg -> addObject(NewObAdded); // attach object to message

NewObject *newObExtracted = (NewObject *) msg -> getObject("message"); // extract object from message
```

I don't know any other ways to add data to a cMessage object.

Answer (score 0):

I just create a msg type and add every thing i need on it, after when sending, i use a send Delayed, setting the time calculated  using the size of the message.

Hope this post helped  you